# Как увеличить значение datetime на 1 день?

Tags: python, datetime

Не удается увеличить значение `datetime` на 1 день. Помогите разобраться.

```
while datecurr < datetarget.__add__(daydelta):
    newdate = datecurr.__add__(daydelta)            
    print(f'{stepcount} " " {datecurr} - {newdate} {newdate.__add__(1)} ')


datenow = datetime.date.now()


# if datenow > datecurr and datenow < newdate.__add__(0, 0, 1):
if datenow > datecurr and datenow < newdate.__add__(1) : #expected an indented block (<unknown>, line 28)
```

Comment: как именно "не удается"? И еще увеличить "datetime на 1" чего (день, секунда, апельсин)?

Comment: Не удается увеличить на один день. Надеюсь здесь мне удалось увеличить на 1 день?
newdate.__add__(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [217]: from datetime import datetime as DT, timedelta

In [218]: DT.now() + timedelta(days=1)
Out[218]: datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 15, 59, 33, 804180)
```

как правильно сделать проверку `if datenow > datecurr and datenow < newdate.__add__(1)`:

```
if datecurr < datenow < newdate + timedelta(days=1):
    ...
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, MaxU!
А возможно ли прирастить значение в 1 день находясь в условии if? или только выносить, увеличение переменной за пределы условия? if datenow > datecurr and datenow < newdate.__add__(1)-

Comment: @dog3000, что вы понимаете под словом «прирастить»?

Comment: @MaxU `as DT`, а при этом `DT` никак не используется, тщятельнее надоть )

Comment: @MaxU Прирастить - это увеличить значение на определенную величину. В данном случае, стоит задача увеличить значение newdate на 1 день находясь в операторе ветвления if

Comment: @dog3000, увеличить для проверки или так, чтобы __после проверки__ значение `newdate` оказалось увеличинным на один день?

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, исправил)

Comment: @MaxU увеличить только для проверки условия, без переопределения переменной newdate